# PHP Arrays, Add and move current array indexes

Tags: php, arrays

I got this:

```
$arr = array();
$arr[0] = "Test";
$arr[1] = "Bla";
$arr[2] = "Boo";
```

Now I would like to add "SO" to this array, but in the start of the array, the [0] index. But without removing the current, so it should instead move the rest of the content, so "Test" gets to be [1] and Bla is [2] and Boo is [3].

How can this be done?

Comment: `array_unshift($arr, 'SO');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to make use of [array_unshift()](http://www.php.net/array_unshift)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the array manipulation functions. `array_unshift()` should do what you want. Other similar functions are array_shift(), array_pop(), and array_push()